# how to find left,right,top,bottom View

Tags: android, view, imageview, tablelayout, tablerow

I need to know left,right,top,bottom(LRTB) View of each View added in TableLayout
Scenario as below

TableLayout has 3 TableRows
Each TableRow has 3 ImageViews
Like a 3x3 matrix of ImageViews

> XXX
>  XXX
>  XXX

I know TableLayout and TableRow has a method named as getChildAt(int index)
but how to use that method or any other ways to find the LRTB Views of each View

Comment: Please elaborate more..what you want to achieve?? also Can you provide some code so that someone can really help...

Comment: If you are trying to make a game like TIC TAC TOE. Then I can help...

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are working on tick tac toe kinda app. So basically you'll need a TableLayout with 3 TableRow in it. Each row will have 3 child views. So if you want to get the LRTB views, you can call these methods -

```
View getLeft(View view){
    TableRow row = (TableRow) view.getParent();
    int pos = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<3;i++){
       if(view == row.getChildAt(i)){
          pos = i;
          break;
       }
    }
    if(pos==0)
        return null;
    return row.getChildAt(pos-1);
}


View getRight(View view){
    TableRow row = (TableRow) view.getParent();
    int pos = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<3;i++){
       if(view == row.getChildAt(i)){
          pos = i;
          break;
       }
    }
    if(pos==2)
        return null;
    return row.getChildAt(pos+1);
}

View getTop(View view){
    TableRow row = (TableRow) view.getParent();
    int rowPos = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<3;i++){
        if(tableLayout.getChildAt(i)==row){
            rowPos=i;
        }
    }
    int pos = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<3;i++){
       if(view == row.getChildAt(i)){
          pos = i;
          break;
       }
    }
    if(pos==0 || rowPos==0)
        return null;
    return tableLayout.getChildAt(rowPos-1).getChildAt(pos-1);
}

View getBottom(View view){
    TableRow row = (TableRow) view.getParent();
    int rowPos = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<3;i++){
        if(tableLayout.getChildAt(i)==row){
            rowPos=i;
        }
    }
    int pos = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<3;i++){
       if(view == row.getChildAt(i)){
          pos = i;
          break;
       }
    }
    if(pos==2 || rowPos==2)
        return null;
    return tableLayout.getChildAt(rowPos+1).getChildAt(pos+1);
}
```

Comment: However if you just keep an object of each view and have a property set for each of them, it'd be much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getChildAt()` method to determine are in which position of any of your rows. This will cover getting left/right views. You could try to use the TableLayout's getChildAt method to find the rows, but that may be more trouble than it is worth. However, to make it a bit simpler you could just set up functions for each imageView, such as

```
getTopLeft(){ 
    myTableLayout.getChildAt(0).getChildAt(0); 
}
getTopMiddle(){ 
    myTableLayout.getChildAt(0).getChildAt(1); 
}
getTopRight(){ 
    myTableLayout.getChildAt(0).getChildAt(2); 
}
```

, etc.

However, it may be simpler to just keep track of which row is above/below the current row using proper naming of rows (e.g. row_top, row_middle, row_bottom) and use the other row's `getChildAt()` method.

However, I should note that all of these methods require you to at least know the position of the view you are looking at. There is not a good way to know which view is above a given view unless you know where that given view is. But honestly, instead of adding/removing ImageViews from the rows you might consider just changing their drawable, this way you could build methods which take in the ID of the view and return the views above, below, etc.